# Python pairs have multiple copies of a word in list

Tags: python-2.7, list, jython-2.7

So I have the following code:

```
def stripNonAlphaNum(text):
    import re
    return re.compile(r'\W+', re.UNICODE).split(text)

def readText(fileStub):
  words = open(fileStub, 'r').read()
  words = words.lower() # Make it lowercase
  wordlist = sorted(stripNonAlphaNum(words))
  wordfreq = []
  for w in wordlist: # Increase count of one upon every iteration of the word.
    wordfreq.append(wordlist.count(w))
  return list(zip(wordlist, wordfreq))
```

It reads a file in, and then makes pairs of the word and frequency in which they occur. The issue I'm facing is that when I print the result, I don't get the proper pair counts.

If I have some input given, I might get output like this:

> ('and', 27), ('and', 27), ('and', 27), ('and', 27), ('and', 27), ('and', 27), ('and', 27),.. (27 times)

Which is NOT what I want it to do.

Rather I would like it to give 1 output of the word and just one number like so:

> ('and', 27), ('able', 5), ('bat', 6).. etc

So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a dictionary. 
Dictionaries work like hash maps, thus allow associative indexing; in this way duplicates are not an issue.

```
...
  wordfreq = {}
  for w in wordlist: 
    wordfreq[w] = wordlist.count(w)
  return wordfreq
```

If you really need to return a list, just do `return wordfreq.items()`

The only problem with this approach is that you will unnecessarily compute the wordlist.count() method more than once for each word.
To avoid this issue, write `for w in set(wordlist):`

Edit for additional question: if you are ok with returning a list, just do `return sorted(wordfreq.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])`. If you omit the key part, the result will be ordered by the word first, then the value

Comment: This works great! One edit if you can do it, how do I make the items in dictionary sorted according to number of items and alphabetically? So for everything with '1' as a value, I need that to be sorted alphabetically, and so on.

Comment: Edited the answer, hope it fits your needs